# Batch File: Error in relative path , one level up from the current directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, path

I am new to the batch script programming.Getting error while executing batch file if I give the relative path.
I have following folder structure

```
Script folder - C:\batch\script\ServiceRegister.bat
Bin path - C:\batch\bin\ERecruitGenerateReportsWindowsService.exe
```

ServiceRegister.bat Batch file –

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe %~dp0%~1\bin\ERecruitGenerateReportsWindowsService.exe
```

When I execute ServiceRegister.bat file I got the error:

```
Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\batch\script\bin\ERecruitGenerateReportsWindowsService.exe' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I am using “%~dp0%~1” to go one level up in the directory still it gets its current path.

```
%~dp0%~1 - C:\batch\script\
```

I need the C:\batch\  path. How I can get this path?
It works fine If I give the absolute path -

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe C:\batch\bin\ERecruitGenerateReportsWindowsService.exe
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your attempt to use `%~1` to go up one level in the directory structure is inventive and totally invalid syntax. The proper syntax is just as simple - use `..\`.

A leading `\` is not required because `%~dp0` ends with a `\`.

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe %~dp0..\bin\ERecruitGenerateReportsWindowsService.exe
```