# Get the path two directories up in batch file

Tags: batch-file, path

I want to get the path of a folder that is 2 directories up from the current location.

I am doing the following:

```
echo %CD%
set NEW_PATH = ..\..\bin\
echo %PATH%
```

When I run the above I get the current directory path printed but the NEW_PATH isnt.. It just says ECHO_OFF.

From this link: [Batch File: Error in relative path , one level up from the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960880/batch-file-error-in-relative-path-one-level-up-from-the-current-directory) I have also tried

```
set NEW_PATH = %~dp0..\..\bin\
```

but still the same problem.

How can I get this directory path?

Answer (score 7):

For each folder, `..` points to its parent folder, so, two levels up from current folder is `..\..`. Now, to convert the relative reference to a absolute full path, we need to get a reference to the pointed file/folder. To do it we can pass the relative reference as an argument to a subroutine or we can use a `for` command

```dos
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "newDir=..\..\bin"

    rem With a subroutine   
    call :resolve "%newDir%" resolvedDir
    echo %resolvedDir%

    rem With a for - retrieve the full path of the file/folder being
    rem              referenced by the for replaceable parameter
    for %%f in ("%newDir%") do echo %%~ff

    endlocal
    goto :EOF

:resolve file/folder returnVarName
    rem Set the second argument (variable name) 
    rem to the full path to the first argument (file/folder)
    set "%~2=%~f1"
    goto :EOF
```

EDIT

The submitted code gets relative path for the current directory, not batch file directory. If batch file relative is what you need, try

```dos
set "newDir=%~dp0\..\..\bin\"
```

where `%~dp0` is the drive and path of the current batch file (`%0` is a reference to the current batch file) and proced with the same/similar code

Comment: Would be great if you could elaborate the meaning of once of these two approaches. This gave me enough to do what I wanted, but had I have needed to traverse 3 levels up, I wouldn't have known how to modify it to do what I needed.

Comment: For anyone looking to understand what's going on in this answer with %~f etc., the accepted answer on this question has some useful documentation for that syntax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem today but a little different, I had to call a bat from another folder and this is how i solve it:

```
@echo off    

rem tree

rem  <driver>
rem    |
rem   root
rem    |-- A
rem        |-- B
rem            |-- C
rem                |-- test.bat
rem    |-- D
rem        |-- E
rem            |-- testD.bat
rem        |-- testSibling.bat 


rem  take current dir
set "crt_dir=%~dp0"

rem go 3 levels up 
for %%I in ("%crt_dir%\..\..\..") do set "root=%%~fI"

set "sibling=%root%\D

set "insideSibling=%sibling%\E

echo +----------------------------------------------+
echo + current dir   -- "%crt_dir%"
echo + root dir      -- "%root%"
echo + siblling      -- "%sibling%"
echo + insideSibling -- "%insideSibling%"
echo +----------------------------------------------+

call %sibling%\siblingTest.bat
call %insideSibling%\testD.bat
```

SiblingTest.bat :

```
echo    +---------------------------------------+
echo    + inside sibling folder "%~dp0"
echo    +---------------------------------------+
```

testD.bat

```
echo    +---------------------------------------+
echo    + inside D folder "%~dp0"
echo    +---------------------------------------+
```

And the output is this:

[image]